# C++ programs, compiling with g++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

I am very aware of compiling C++ programs with g++ in linux environment. But, may be I am missing something, I am getting this strange output/behaviour.

I have source file in test.cpp.
To compile this, I did

```
(1)
g++ -c test.cpp 
g++ -o test test.o
./test
```

Everything works fine. 
But when I did compling and linking in same stage, like this

```
(2)
g++ test.cpp -o test 
./test => Works fine
(3)
g++ -c test.cpp -o test => Doesn't work
```

In my last case, test is generated but is no more executable; but in my guess it should work fine.
So, what is wrong or do I need to change some settings/configuration ??

I am using g++ 4.3.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you say:

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test
```

The -c flag inhibits linking, so no executable is produced - you are renaming the .o file.

Basically, don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

You are forcing compiler to produce an object file and name it like an executable.

Essentially your last line tells: compile this to an object file, but name it test, instead of test.obj.

Answer (score 3):

-c flag means Compile Only

Try 
g++ -o test test.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `-o` in the g++ command line tells the compiler what name to give the output file. When you tried to do it all in one line, you just told the compiler to compile `test.cpp` as an object file named `test`, and no linking was done.

Have a look at the fabulous [online manual for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

from the gcc manual:

> ```
>   -c  Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking
>       stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form of an
>       object file for each source file.
> ```

You must link the compiled object files to get the executable file.
More info about compiling and linking and stuff is [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node3.html#fig:comp).

Answer (score 1):

Read man g++. The switch  -c is to compile only but not to link.
g++ -c test.cpp -o test
does what
g++ -c test.cpp
does but the object file will be test istead of the default name test.o. An object file cannot be executed.